# How to make a correct abstract entity class

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I'm looking to make an abstract class Entity which then has few classes that derive from it like Enemy, Friendly and Player. The reason I do this is because the classes have a lot of properties/fields that are alike. I also have 2 methods: `updateEntity` and `drawEntity`. The reason I have the update and draw entity is that `drawEntity` & `updateEntity` is the same for most of the classes that inherit from it. This is the code of my entity class:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private Texture2D texture;

    public Texture2D Texture
    {
        get { return texture; }
        set { texture = value; }
    }

    private Vector2 position;

    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }

    private int health;

    public int Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set { health = value; }
    }

    private Color entColor;

    public Color EntColor
    {
        get { return entColor; }
        set { entColor = value; }
    }

    public Entity(string name, Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, int health, Color entColor)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.texture = texture;
        this.position = position;
        this.health = health;
        this.entColor = entColor;
    }

    public virtual void updateEntity(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //update stuff here
    }

    public virtual void drawEntity(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height), entColor);
    }
}
```

And this is how I envision my Enemy class :

```
public Enemy(string name, Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, int health, Color entColor)
{
    Name = name;
    Texture = texture;
    Position = position;
    Health = health;
    EntColor = entColor;
}
```

Can anybody tell me if this is a good use of abstract class or if I'm doing something completely wrong in game design/architecture way?

Comment: There's no real reason to mark it abstract without any abstract methods inside it, unless you really don't want to allow new instances of it to be created. Mark it abstract when-You have some core functionality that should be shared across child classes and you also require these child classes to provide their own unique functionality which is defined by the abstract method in the parent class. Have a read on the Template Method Pattern, it will explain a core usage of abstract classes very well.

Comment: @William Thanks for the reply, I took a look at your suggestion on the Template Method Pattern, and it was a very interesting explanation of abstract classes. Thanks very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You usually use an abstract class when its implementation is not complete to work with but it contains properties and/or methods that are common for other types that are derived from it or it provides an interface that should be shared by derived types but cannot be implemented at this lever of abstraction and thus it is not possible to instantiate it.

Such an example could be an abstract class `Fruit` that has a `Color` property that is common to all fruits and doesn't have to be implemented by each one of them. It can also have a method `Grow()` without implementation. This class alone *makes no sense* yet. You need to implement a concrete fruit like an `Apple` type and implement the `Grow()` method for this particular fruit.

In your case the `Entity` would be such a fruit and the apple could be a rectangle or a circle that implement their own drawing logic.

Base entity:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public abstract void Draw(); // no implementation here

    public virtual void UpdateEntity(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // default update
    }
}
```

Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle : Entity
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // draw a rectangle here
    }
}
```

Circle which uses a different logic for `UpdateEntity`:

```
public class Circle : Entity
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // draw a circle here
    }

    public override void UpdateEntity(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // custom update for circles
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i got a clear view on when to use abstract classes :)